# Activate onchange after changing content with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why wouldn't onChange function of an input be activated when the value of the input is changed by javascript? For example why when clicking on the button alert wouldn't happen?

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" id="myInput" onchange="alert(1)" />
<button onclick = "document.getElementById('myInput').value = 'ads'">click</button>
</body>    
</html>
```

How can I make the onchange function work then?

edit:
I now understand event won't be triggered automatically, how can I call it(jquery too) ?

Comment: The `change` event is not triggered when the value is changed programmatically... that's just how it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scripted value changes don't trigger an event. You have to manually trigger an event.

jQuery: `$('#myInput').trigger('change');`

Add the following code to the `onchange` event:

```
var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
if(input.fireEvent) input.fireEvent("onchange");
else {
    var ev = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
    ev.initEvent("change", true, false);
    input.dispatchEvent(ev);
}
```

So, combined with your code (you should actually separate the JS code from the HTML):

```
<button onclick="var input = document.getElementById('myInput');input.value = 'ads';if(input.fireEvent)input.fireEvent('onchange');else{var ev=document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');ev.initEvent('change',true,false);input.dispatchEvent(ev);}">click</button>
```